# Confused with X.ORG version number

Tags: 11.10, xorg, ati

There is my trouble: I'm trying to install ATI drivers on my Dell Vostro 3350 laptop. On the AMD's site I followed steps to determine which driver should I use. After selecting what hardware I use I got a link to download `amd-driver-installer-12-3-x86.x86_64.run` and below was a description of that driver that it was compatible with X.Org version from 6.7 to 7.6. And I do not know what version of X.Org my Ubuntu uses. Cause after googling I found that version is 7.6 in Ubuntu 11.10. But after typing: `X -version` I got the output:

```
X.Org X Server 1.10.4
Release Date: 2011-08-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
```

So what is the exact version of X.Org in Ubuntu 11.10 and how should one reliably determine it? Can anyone construe? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The X Window System used to be distributed as one big tarball containing the server, drivers, client libraries and some applications.

This changed with the release of X11R7.0, where these components were split into separate tarballs.  The main benefits being:

1. If a component doesn't change between releases, the same tarball can be included in multiple releases.
2. More frequently changing components (such as graphics drivers) can release new packages that can be installed without having to rebuild everything else.
3. Different people can handle the release of different components.

It does have one downside in that the version numbers of all the different components are now more visible to users.

In the case of the X server itself, you can see what version was included in X11R7.6 at the download site:

http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/src/xserver/

So the version included with Ubuntu 11.10 is somewhat newer.  The driver you downloaded from AMD may be compatible with the newer server, but AMD is unlikely to advertise this one way or the other until a full X11R7.7 release is out.  If you are concerned, I suggest sticking to the driver versions included with Ubuntu.